# Spring Data JPA date query doesn't work for Date been and date greater than

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to query using Spring data JPA, with the following queries. But I could get the fileted output between any given dates.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT new com.xxx.DonationByUserTotal(d.club.name, d.club.id , d.club.logo, SUM(d.amount)) " +
        "from Donation d where d.user.id=?1 and d.createdDate  >= ?2 GROUP BY d.club")
List<DonationByUserTotal> findByUserAndFromDate(int User, @Param("fromDate") Date fromDate);
```

This query returns all the dates for the given user but doesn't filter between given dates.

```
@Query("SELECT new com.xxx.DonationByUserTotal(d.club.name, d.club.id , d.club.logo, SUM(d.amount) )" +
        "from Donation d where d.user.id=?1 and d.createdDate BETWEEN ?2 and  ?3  GROUP BY d.club")
List<DonationByUserTotal> findByUserAndBetweenDates(int User,@Param("from")Date fromDate,@Param("to") Date toDate);
```

This query returns an empty set despite valid dates between.

Can someone help me to solve this?

PS:

The entity class is using the

```
@CreatedDate
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
private Date createdDate;
```

and the parameters passed to query also with a timestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure, that the error was due to a different format in date. Because the spring didn't throw any errors, it was difficult to figure it out.